# Error trying to add some data from Firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I have a code like this, where I'm trying to add some data from a Realtime Database on Firebase to my local variable and got this is the error on the line where I try to add the information from Firebase to my variable, on the line where I use the +=

> No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'

```
@State private var vRMtratamiento: Double = 0.000

(...)

VStack{
    if !viewModel.listObject_BudgetD.isEmpty {
        ForEach(1...31, id: \.self) { i in
            let temp = validarfecha(i: i)
            if let object = viewModel.listObject_BudgetD.first(where: { $0.id == Int(temp) }) {
                vRMtratamiento += object.tratamiento
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.observeListObjectsD()
        }
```

Both of my variables are Double, and when I print `object.tratamiento`, I got the correct data.

Comment: you cannot have that type of procedural code in a `ForEach`. The `ForEach` must return other views, it is not the "normal" for loop. Review what SwiftUI is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the basics of SwiftUI, it is different than Swift.
You **cannot** have that type of procedural code in a `ForEach`. A `ForEach` must return other views.

Try something like this, where you put your procedural code
in the `.onAppear{...}` or in a separate function, but not inside a `ForEach`.

```
 VStack {
     if !viewModel.listObject_BudgetD.isEmpty {
         Text("vRMtratamiento: \(vRMtratamiento)") // <--- here a View
     }
 }
 // -- here
 .onAppear {
     viewModel.observeListObjectsD()  // <-- not async
     // -- here, procedural code, or in a separate function
     for i in 1...31 {
         let temp = validarfecha(i: i)
         if let object = viewModel.listObject_BudgetD.first(where: { $0.id == Int(temp) }) {
             vRMtratamiento += object.tratamiento
         }
     }

 }
```